# How can I make my raylib library work on macOS?

Tags: macos, raylib

[ERROR MESSAGE AFTER TRYING TO COMPILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FndmT.jpg)I've bought new M.2 Mac, im still kinda beginner in learning C++ and I wanted to try making games using raylib library. First it wanted me to compile using c++11 or later, which I've solved. but now I have another problem, libraries are detected and everything, but when I want to compile and start the game, it says "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" I will post a photo as well and I don't know how to solve it. Please help somebody.

for compiling im using clang mostly, and I use vscode bus I don't really like the Xcode, but its not the IDEs issues, its seems like the compiler just can't find these keywords in the library.

I've just started to make a new project, so its looks like this:

```
#include "/Users/zapletalf/Documents/code/raylib/Template-4.0.0/raylib.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{



const int screen_width = 1280;
const int screen_height = 800;
cout << "Starting the game.." << endl;

InitWindow(screen_width, screen_height, "My pong game");
SetTargetFPS(60);

while (WindowShouldClose() == false)
{
    BeginDrawing();

    EndDrawing();

}



CloseWindow();
```

}